# Silhouette Score for ordered clusters

Tags: r, machine-learning, time-series, clustering, unsupervised-learning

My clusters are arranged according to a time series, and I want to compute the silhouette score for the clustering performed, considering that they follow an order. Therefore the nearest cluster to the present cluster will be the one that comes next in the time series.
What I have tried,

*Data*

```
# Sample Matrix
cell_1 <- c(2,2,4)
cell_2 <- c(2,3,2)
cell_3 <- c(0,1,2)
cell_4 <- c(0,2,1)
cell_5 <- c(5,2,3)
cell_6 <- c(9,2,3)
cell_7 <- c(1,2,3)
cell_8 <- c(0,2,1)
cell_9 <- c(5,2,5)
cell_10 <- c(9,2,3)
test_mat <- as.matrix(rbind(cell_1, cell_2, cell_3, cell_4, cell_5,
                            cell_6, cell_7, cell_8, cell_9, cell_10))
colnames(test_mat) <- c("gene1", "gene2", "gene3")

# Cluster information
cluster.time.series <- data.frame(label = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3),
 member = c("cell_1", "cell_2", "cell_3", "cell_4", "cell_5",
            "cell_6", "cell_7", "cell_8", "cell_9", "cell_10"))
```

*Calculation intra cluster mean*

```
unique_clusters <- unique(cluster.time.series$label)
cluster_means <- NULL
for (i in unique_clusters) {
    
    # Select cells of the clusters
    sel_cells <- test_mat[rownames(test_mat) %in% cluster.time.series[cluster.time.series$label == i, "member"], ]
    
    # Calculate distance
    sel_cells_dist <- dist(sel_cells, method = "euclidean")
    
  # Subset distance matrix and calculate mean
  cluster_means <- c(cluster_means, mean(sel_cells_dist))
}
cluster_means
```

*Calculation of separation based on the natural order of cluster labels*

```
nearest_means <- NULL
for (i in unique_clusters) {
    
    # Select cells of present cluster
    sel_cells <- test_mat[rownames(test_mat) %in% cluster.time.series[cluster.time.series$label == i, "member"], ]

    # Save present cluster Index
    present_clus_index <- which(unique_clusters == i)
    
    if (present_clus_index + 1 > length(unique_clusters)){break}
    
    next_cluster_index <- present_clus_index + 1
    
    # Select the successive cluster
    next_cluster <- unique_clusters[next_cluster_index]

    # Next cluster cells
    next_sel_cells <- test_mat[rownames(test_mat) %in% cluster.time.series[cluster.time.series$label == next_cluster, "member"], ]
    
    # R-bind
    combined.matrix <- rbind(sel_cells, next_sel_cells)
    combined.matrix.dist <- dist(combined.matrix, method = "euclidean")
    
    # Make all possible links of the cells 
    separation_points <- as.data.frame(crossing(rownames(sel_cells),rownames(next_sel_cells)))
    colnames(separation_points) <- c("present", "next")
    
    
    # nearest mean
    mean_vec <- apply(separation_points, 1,function(x, dist_mat = as.matrix(combined.matrix.dist)){
       
        # Make a matrix
        vals <- dist_mat[rownames(dist_mat) == x[1],
                         colnames(dist_mat) == x[2]]
    })
    
    print(length(mean_vec))
    tot_mean <- mean(mean_vec)    
    
    print(paste(i, "with", next_cluster, "nearest mean: ", tot_mean))
    
    # Distance of point 
  nearest_means <- c(nearest_means, tot_mean)
  
}
```

*Calculation of Silhouette Score*

```
# calculate silhouette score for each data point
silhouette_scores <- (nearest_means - cluster_means[-4]) / pmax(nearest_means, cluster_means[-4])
mean(silhouette_scores)
```

*Problems with the script*

1. I have a huge data matrix, and this script consumes too much time
2. I implemented it using the silhouette score formula; however, different websites show different methods. I am not confident enough that it is a right implementation.
3. Is there a library which to compute silhouette score taking into account cluster order

Comment: for the silhouette check the `cluster` package.

Comment: In Silhouette statistic, the "nearest other cluster" is the one nearest to a particular point, object. So it is (may be) different for different members even belonging to one and the same cluster.